# Camera freezes after sleep

Tags: android, android-camera

This method is called from onResume()

```
 private void initCameraPreview() {
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
    mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, mSurfaceView.getHolder());
}

private Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

This is my onPause()

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    isPicTaken = false;

    mCameraPreview.surfaceDestroyed(null);

    Log.d("MainCameraActivity", "OnPause()");
    super.onPause();
}
```

This is CameraPreview

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private static String TAG = "Camera Preview class";
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private static boolean previewIsRunning;

public Camera getmCamera() {
    return mCamera;
}

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera mCamera, SurfaceHolder holder) {
    super(context);

    mHolder = holder;
    this.mCamera = mCamera;

    if (mHolder != null) {
        mHolder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        mHolder.setSizeFromLayout();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setFocusMode("continuous-picture");
        params.setRotation(90);

        mCamera.setParameters(params);

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.startPreview();

        previewIsRunning = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        myStopPreview();
        mCamera = null;
    }
    previewIsRunning = false;
}

public void myStartPreview() {
    if (!previewIsRunning) {
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            params.setFocusMode("continuous-picture");
            params.setRotation(90);

            mCamera.setParameters(params);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.startPreview();

            previewIsRunning = true;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void myStopPreview() {
    if (previewIsRunning) {
        mHolder.removeCallback(this);

        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();

        previewIsRunning = false;
    }

}
```

}

This code works if I go to another activity, and back, minimize application, and open it again, but if I make phone sleep, and then wake up, picture in preview freezes, and after calling for takePicture I get this

```
07-25 18:00:00.970  11395-11395/com.woxapp.pricehelper.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
        at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
        at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1100)
        at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1045)
        at com.woxapp.pricehelper.app.activities.MainCameraActivity.onTakePhotoButtonClicked(MainCameraActivity.java:683)
        at com.woxapp.pricehelper.app.views.MainCameraView$11.onClick(MainCameraView.java:545)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I really don't know how it's possible, and how to solve this issue, testing on Nexus 4 (Android 4.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the mSurfaceView's oncreated and onchanged can not be call.
the most simple way is just set mSurfaceView invisible and visible in the onpause and onresume. in your activity or fragment, add this code:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCamera = Camera.open(0);
    mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);// this can fix the freeze.
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);//this to fix freeze.
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `initCameraPreview()` assumes that `mCamera` must be obtained by your app; probably somewhere, e.g. `onStop()` you also release the camera (or the system takes care of that for you). But when you put the phone to sleep and then wake up, only `onPause()` and `onResume()` are called for the current activity.

So, you should make sure you don't try to acquire the camera when it's already yours. One easy way is to add `mCamera = null;` immediately after you call to `mCamera.close()`; and it case you don't - add this to `onStop()` method of your Activity.

Then, in `initCameraPreview()` you can simply check

```
if (mCamera == null) {
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
}
```